# E-mail attachment in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the below code as my email attachment code. But it give me an error that I am unable to figure out the source. all the disposition lines are throwing an error and `new Attachment(FileAttachment, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);` as well

```
    if (FileAttachment != null){
        // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
        Attachment data = new Attachment(FileAttachment, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
       // Add time stamp information for the file.
       ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
       disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(FileAttachment);
       disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(FileAttachment);
       disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(FileAttachment);
       // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
       AllMailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);
    }
```

The erorr Message for the line "new Attachment(FileAttachment, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);"

```
Class System.Net.Mime.Media Typenames
specifies the media type information for email message attachment

Error:

The best overloaded method match for "System.Net.Mail.Attachment.Attachment..." has some invalid arguments
```

For the Three lines of IO.File i.e System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(FileAttachment);

the Error is the same

```
The best overloaded method match for "System.IO.File...." has some invalid arguments
```

asp.Net fileupload code

```
<td class="FileUpload">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileAttachment" runat="server" />
                </td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't know what error you're experiencing unless you add the exception message to your question.

Comment: "Throwing an error" is just what every programmer needs when receiving a bug report

Comment: I have added the errors now..sorry for that

Comment: What is `FileAttachment`

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileAttachment" runat="server" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachment constructor can not get a `FileUpload` as argument. It needs a `String` or a `Stream`.
You can get the uploaded file stream from `FileContent` property of `FileUpload`.

```
Attachment data = new Attachment(FileAttachment.FileContent, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that `FileUpload` is not valid as an argument to the `Attachment` class

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for the definition of `Attachment`

You'll need to convert the file in `Attachment` to a stream to be used as parameter

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\ws_Log.txt"));
```